# Jsoup - how to submit form

Tags: android, jsoup

I would like to submit a form in a specific website for my android app:
 http://www.mp3juices.cc/

Here is the website in chrome dev tool:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tro2.png)

I tried to use Jsoup, but It gives me the same page before the search (before sending the form).

Here is my code:

```
Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .method(Connection.Method.GET)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.109 Safari/537.36")
                    .referrer(url)
                    .execute();
Map<String,String> mCookies = response.cookies();
response = Jsoup.connect(url)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.109 Safari/537.36")
                    .method(Connection.Method.POST)
                    .cookies(mCookies)
                    .data("query","song name")
                    .referrer(url)
                    .execute();
//here im printing that document and it is unchanged.
doc = response.parse().toString();
```

I want it to send a text to the search box form, return me the updated page,and then I'll be able to select the results(div).

Please help me understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: why down vote??

Comment: What if the server requires a `Referrer` header?

Comment: It may be good to supply a `Jsoup.userAgent(...)` too.

Comment: I did what you said, but still nothing. (in the 'Referrer' i entered the same url of the page).

Comment: For such tasks I usually use Chrome Dev Tools. Open that page in Chrome. Press F12. Do the query manually or hit F5. Open 'Network' tab. Then from the list select the index.html page. Then on right you'll see the HTTP request and response. Inspect exactly what headers contains the HTTP request and replicate them in your code.

Comment: You've forgotten the `data("query"...)` line in your last edit.

Comment: Thanks, I updated it. but it still not working...

Comment: I've just taken a look. This site has a fairly dynamic way to retrieve the data.    Everything is managed in JS and jQuery. Won't be so easy to just scrape it. The JS script requests and dynamically updates the HTML from the results. The `script.js` file is the workhorse.

Comment: So what steps should I make?

Comment: I've never have such a dynamic JS site to scrape. It seems that Jsoup scraping is not the proper way with this site. I think it might be easier to just communicate with the same APIs as mp3juices.cc does. I suppose they are all free.

Comment: Are are you sure? Because when the form is submited, a new div with the results is created, isnt it possible to scrape and achieve it?

Comment: In theory it's possible. But you should somehow hook the JS event that is modifying the DOM and scrape the HTML of the new DOM. I guess it's something simple in JS but I have no experience with it. The problem with Jsoup and JS is that the Jsoup client is not a Javascript VM. It doesn't handle anything JS-related. You may use some hidden WebView as a JS VM and scrape the html taken from WebView. It should be possible. But the approach is too hacky and error prone. Direct interaction with network APIs is preferable, harder to break and easier to maintain.

Comment: All right, Thanks for your help